# meta description/tag not working

Tags: html, tags, meta

I am having a very strange problem. The meta tag was working befor on my home page.. but now for some reason not anymore. It does not show the title correctly in google, neither the description that I am looking for. 
I am having the feeling that the meta-tag gets blocked in some way.
the only big thing I have done is gzipping the site.. but I am not sure that is the issue. I dont know what part of code I should post, I don´t really feel like posting a huge nofollow link.

but I was thinking maybe somebody here can bring me on the right path how to fix this issue? what could be the problem?

edit: the meta part

```
     <head>

     <title>Open Minded Life Path - How to change your life</title>
     <meta name="description" content="A collection of positve thinking, how to change                 life-guides, life changing solutions by free thinking and a positive apprauch. Tested self motivation techniques. ">
     <meta name="keywords" content="Positive thinking, How to change your life, how  to change, how to start  new life, how to change yourself, life changing solutions, unclutter, free thinking, life changes, positive approach, lifestyle, positive thinking, self motivation techniques, what is a life coach">
    <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="INDEX, FOLLOW">
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: show the metatags, they should all be in between the <head></head> tags

Answer (score 5):

Google [says](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=en#1):

> The description attribute within the `<meta>` tag is a good way to provide a concise, human-readable summary of each page’s content. **Google will sometimes use the meta description** of a page in search results snippets, if we think it gives users a more accurate description than would be possible purely from the on-page content. Accurate meta descriptions can help improve your clickthrough; here are some guidelines for properly using the meta description.

You can't control how Google will present your site in search results. You can only make suggestions. They won't use them if their algorithm thinks it can give a better representation of the page.